# How to express this exponential equation in terms of $m$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How can I express the equation

> $c = 2^{m+1} - 2^m$

in terms of m? t.i.a.

Comment: It already seems to be expressed in terms of $m$. Please clarify what you want.

Answer (score 3):

What do you means by write in term of $m$? Do you means simplify? Do you mean any of the following?

$c = 2^{m}(2 - 1) = 2^{m}(1) = 2^m$

or $m = log_2 c$.

Comment: If you are asking the OP for clarification, please do so in the comments.

Comment: I'd be surprised if OP meant anything other than "solve for $m$ in terms of $c$," and in that context this qualifies as an answer.